# Android - Youtube Player Stop an video at specified time

Tags: android, video, youtube

I'm trying to play an `youtube video` using `Youtube Video Player` in my `android app` from given `start_time` and `end_time.`

I used `player.loadVideo("_wcs7ixyDbY", 12000),` so that my video starts playing after `12 seconds.` But I want to end my video at `20 seconds`.

I used

```
player.loadVideo(videoID, 12000);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(player.getCurrentTimeMillis() <= 20000) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            player.pause();
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

This option `pause` my `video` after `20 seconds.`

How to end my `video` after `20 seconds (not pause)`

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The Android YouTube API provides a method to stop / release the video also:

> abstract void release()
>
> Stop any loading or video playback and release any system resources used by this YouTubePlayer.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer