# End Video Youtube at special time in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I already loaded a video on an Android phone using `YouTubePlayerView`. Now I want to end video at `currentTime`. I called `youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis()` but it's not working.

I also want to play video without ads. How to do that? Please help me.

Here is document: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener

Comment: at the moment the web version of the player is not showing ads, checkout this library that I've built, if you're interested. https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player
That's the only way to play videos without ads. May change in the future if YouTube updates its web player.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021784/android-youtube-player-stop-an-video-at-specified-time). It suggested to use [`abstract void release()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#release()) method which stops any loading or video playback and releases any system resources used by this `YouTubePlayer`. Additional reference:  [How to provide start and end parameters for a youtube video in youtube Android player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565494/how-to-provide-start-and-end-parameters-for-a-youtube-video-in-youtube-android-p?rq=1)

Regarding **playing video withoud ads**, check this link [Embed YouTube Video with No Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981310/embed-youtube-video-with-no-ads).

> [Whether ads are shown on a video is up to the content owner of that video. It's not something that the embedder can control.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en)
>
> If you had permission from the content owners of the videos to upload copies in your own account, and then ensured that your account was set up with monetization turned off, then that would prevent ads from showing during playback. It's up to you to work out that arrangement/permission with the original videos' owners, of course.

Hope this helps!